# find out if coordinate in range of the camera - android

Tags: android, camera, latitude-longitude, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I am doing a small augmented reality app, and i have these objects which contains longitude and latitude information. I also have the current user location and the compass heading angle. How can I check if the coordinate is within the range of the camera view (No matter what it's distance from the camera is)?

Comment: You can check the longitude and latitude of both, then when they are almost the same (number range) then you can see if it is in range yes or no

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to make it, but I can give you logic if its possible for you to do.Yous should try this if you have not thought about it and you find it feasible. It can be idea or just a crap too.
**You can do it by using current location and compass(like in which direction camera u watching). If the direction of that location from your current location and camera's direction matches then display that location as overlay.**
Try this two links:

[Augmented Reality on Android: Prepping the Camera and Compass](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/1954)

[Augmented Reality on Android: Using GPS and the Accelerometer](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43005/0/page/1)

Found it, this is exactly you want.
[android-augment-reality-framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/w/list)

Comment: yeah, but the point is not only to know if the object is in the range of the camera view, but also to know where in the camera view it will be. i need also to know the angle of the camaera view range.

Comment: This is what you want: http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/w/list